# shp2MySQL GIS Import coordinates not correct

Tags: shapefile, php, mysql

I'm attempting to import the Chicago neighborhood boundaries into a MySQL database from the shapefiles available at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Neighborhoods/9wp7-iasj using SHP2MySQL.

I am able to do it with the Zillows Neighborhood Database and get the correct coordinate boundaries, however when I import the City of Chicago data the featured column displays incorrect coordinates. Any help would be appreciated. For example, I get the following data for neighborhood of Beverly when I import the City of Chicago Data:

```
POLYGON((1166097.9701 1844437.85,1166108.3686 1844412.5465,1166142.3191 1844329.9324,1166206.8876 1844160.9099,1166268.781 1843998.89,1166328.18 1843843.4,1166331.6706 1843834.3,1166364.59 1843748.48,1166395.3401 1843670.43,1166459.4958 1843507.5901,1166488.02 1843435.1899,1166507.8499 1843386.56,1166524.0592 1843344.2297,1166588.2577 1843176.5759,1166614.18 1843108.88,1166649.5218 1843016.8707,1166711.99 1842854.24,1166712.5283 1842852.8394,1166763.1101 1842721.23,1166775.7625 1842690.2201,1166787.24 1842662.09,1166838.15 1842530.25,1166849.8318 1842500,1166861.05 1842470.7,1166911.31 1842343.05,1166916.161 1842331.4873,1166788.92 1842328.42,1166900.22 1842041.16,1166909.74 1842016.6,1166924.02 1841979.74,1166938.3001 1841942.88,1166969.68 1841861.9001,1167009.2 1841759.92,1167028.3324 1841706.3521,1167127.2499 1841708.755,1167176.8286 1841710.124,1167176.8408 1841710.136,1167176.8456 1841710.1246,1167189.9716 1841710.5666,1167316.7132 1841714.834,1167335.1849 1841715.3112,1167335.8813 1841694.2332,1167337.92 1841632.53,1167340.04 1841535.36,1167342.17 1841438.28,1167343.67 1841365.96,1167343.51 1841337.83,1167349.73 1841292.98,1167359.69 1841253.12,1167375.75 1841208.68,1167405.08 1841127.16,1167441.8161 1841030.6886,1167442.52 1841028.84,1167482.72 1840925.98,1167500 1840881.328,1167507.94 1840860.76,1167536.88 1840786.1,1167554.46 1840740.76,1167575.38 1840686.81,1167595.92 1840633.8401,1167626.56 1840555.07,1167650.2399 1840494.24,1167680.86 1840415.42,1167688.004 1840396.8826,1167706.6501 1840348.5,1167759.67 1840210.72,1167786.78 1840140.57,1167816.02 1840065.14,1167832.92 1840021.45,1167841.229 1839999.9999,1167886.92 1839881.96,1167932.4682 1839763.9484,1167960.67 1839690.88,1168011.42 1839559.81,1168045.96 1839470.78,1168067.7599 1839413.51,1168075.07 1839393.29,1168095.38 1839335.99,1168116.78 1839277.06,1168138.42 1839218.44,1168155.84 1839171.26,1168185.9579 1839094.9484,1168114.4 1839092.94,1168064.92 1839091.43,1168008.91 1839090.03,1167941.43 1839088.34,1167862.82 1839087.3901,1167828.5888 1839086.6137,1167724.81 1839084.26,1167653.4642 1839082.1315,1167596.43 1839080.4299,1167500 1839078.0186,1167449.48 1839076.49,1167414.1688 1839075.4747,1167413.7199 1839075.4619,1167348.27 1839073.58,1167263.52 1839071.12,1167180.0247 1839068.5626,1167111.38 1839066.46,1167038.98 1839064.05,1166966.9 1839061.89,1166956.3693 1839061.6327,1166862.52 1839059.34,1166775.4 1839056.58,1166708.24 1839054,1166627.1297 1839051.6925,1166554.98 1839049.64,1166497.71 1839047.36,1166430.38 1839045.18,1166411.0701 1839044.5198,1166345.56 1839042.28,1166256.18 1839039.44,1166171.59 1839037.0299,1166098.8747 1839036.2326,1166100.3282 1838951.1106,1166100.3265 1838904.3256,1166098.78 1838837.22,1166095.63 1838769.58,1166090.89 1838702.03,1166084.56 1838634.62,1166062.11 1838469.51,1166038.62 1838349.8099,1166020.85 1838271.45,1166014.82 1838246.86,1165998.3899 1838184.44,1165980.42 1838122.4499,1165960.94 1838060.91,1165910.48 1837907.01,1165909.16 1837903.27,1165887.42 1837839.23,1165867.21 1837774.69,1165848.5299 1837709.7,1165831.39 1837644.28,1165817.13 1837584.92,1165815.89 1837579.26,1165806.3399 1837531.7099,1165801.06 1837500,1165798.37 1837483.86,1165791.98 1837435.78,1165787.17 1837387.51,1165773.04 1837229.6501,1165761.21 1837091.76,1165753.04 1836991.3,1165744.98 1836894.33,1165736.42 1836776.53,1165724.06 1836629.84,1165710.49 1836472.09,1165703.43 1836388.7,1165694.02 1836275.31,1165682.13 1836130.72,1165667.7501 1835956.12,1165651.0401 1835757.23,1165634.83 1835556.22,1165619.45 1835370.43,1165592.98 1835063.77,1165589.912 1835028.7082,1165587.4 1835000,1165583.55 1834956.09,1165569.62 1834778.96,1165553.89 1834586.59,1165540.98 1834442.41,1165528.08 1834283.56,1165512.91 1834095.5,1165504.8637 1834003.9009,1165503.9072 1833993.0124,1165498.25 1833928.61,1165491.5587 1833845.7001,1165491.5387 1833845.4533,1165483.76 1833749.07,1165479.7915 1833701.6296,1165479.4372 1833696.5274,1165462.65 1833696,1165452.2 1833696.08,1165399.66 1833693.6293,1165325.28 1833690.16,1165275.29 1833689.13,1165220.4401 1833687.44,1165178.48 1833685.8,1165127.33 1833683.6899,1165072.1652 1833681.8793,1165000 1833679.5107,1164946.39 1833677.62,1164894.32 1833675.7,1164829.9901 1833673.34,1164773.25 1833671.28,1164733.78 1833669.99,1164699.02 1833668.86,1164635.79 1833667.3216,1164613.12 1833666.77,1164581.3098 1833665.555,1164525.94 1833663.44,1164466.45 1833661.1,1164416.95 1833659.16,1164372.67 1833657.42,1164328.21 1833655.68,1164264.6401 1833653.5765,1164208.9699 1833651.7344,1164140.84 1833649.48,1164091.42 1833648.52,1164042.01 1833647.56,1163987.62 1833646.26,1163936.53 1833644.7601,1163878.62 1833643.06,1163819.29 1833641.29,1163774.8 1833639.96,1163712.88 1833638.07,1163703 1833637.75,1163608.1399 1833634.7442,1163559.72 1833633.21,1163512.7 1833631.65,1163468.14 1833630.14,1163426.12 1833628.7,1163373.8 1833626.92,1163331.88 1833625.5,1163283.3797 1833623.9822,1163218.76 1833621.96,1163168.83 1833620.32,1163112.08 1833618.46,1163070.13 1833617.0801,1163025.68 1833615.58,1162954.25 1833613.1788,1162894.79 1833611.1799,1162852.78 1833609.8,1162820.56 1833608.73,1162758.64 1833606.8,1162706.93 1833605.4,1162679.71 1833605.2799,1162625.65 1833605.0999,1162553.65 1833604.86,1162516.56 1833604.48,1162500 1833604.9082,1162467.36 1833605.75,1162412.11 1833607.19,1162330 1833607.17,1162290.0182 1833609.9143,1162288.5809 1833653.9957,1162287.03 1833701.56,1162284.5072 1833783.44,1162283.7 1833809.64,1162280.79 1833904.24,1162277.5 1834010.34,1162274.74 1834091.7601,1162271.96 1834173.7201,1162270.18 1834226.5699,1162268.7294 1834275.6455,1162266.23 1834360.2,1162262.32 1834480.7699,1162258.54 1834597.66,1162255.6201 1834687.3401,1162252.56 1834816.32,1162251.19 1834869.4,1162248.4109 1834941.2681,1162246.14 1835000,1162245.86 1835003.66,1162241.6 1835136.42,1162234.98 1835346.64,1162228.52 1835538.56,1162226.6752 1835604.6503,1162223.7 1835711.24,1162218.62 1835865.26,1162212.23 1836088.51,1162210.39 1836149.76,1162206.3607 1836268.5024,1162204.23 1836331.3,1162200.7999 1836449.3,1162194.84 1836634.54,1162189.86 1836801.08,1162185.999 1836932.5369,1162182.61 1837047.92,1162178.64 1837180.42,1162174.3 1837321.72,1162171.5 1837414.34,1162168.9632 1837500,1162168.24 1837524.18,1162166.1011 1837596.5655,1162163.43 1837686.96,1162162.12 1837731.86,1162159.16 1837832.82,1162156.12 1837936.74,1162152.18 1838071.78,1162148.9 1838185.25,1162146.3679 1838269.7515,1162143.28 1838372.8,1162139.58 1838476.12,1162136.9341 1838550.2899,1162136.14 1838572.55,1162133.29 1838666.5,1162129.42 1838794.36,1162125.8437 1838922.7688,1162123.27 1839015.1801,1162121.38 1839091.28,1162118.63 1839184.92,1162115.27 1839281.15,1162111.56 1839394.51,1162108.2 1839507.76,1162105.6728 1839591.8101,1162101.94 1839715.96,1162098.3501 1839819.16,1162094.4201 1839932.2,1162092.2662 1839999.9999,1162092.22 1840001.93,1162087.9899 1840132.6199,1162084.7603 1840242.46,1162081.7 1840346.54,1162079.72 1840421.58,1162076.38 1840547.1,1162072.6 1840689.01,1162069.36 1840780.7,1162065.4985 1840908.12,1162060.74 1841065.14,1162056.96 1841190.58,1162053.14 1841315.75,1162049.26 1841442.2,1162045.5678 1841553.2358,1162044.8947 1841573.4769,1162044.0317 1841599.4303,1162040.5 1841705.64,1162036.84 1841826.3,1162034.7448 1841897.1001,1162030.34 1842045.95,1162027.28 1842148.42,1162024.1822 1842243.52,1162020.76 1842348.58,1162017.5199 1842450.9001,1162015.9892 1842500,1162012.16 1842623.96,1162006.8599 1842802.46,1162004.8546 1842870.7018,1162001.92 1842970.56,1161996.1788 1843152.1926,1161995.64 1843169.24,1161990.08 1843342.74,1161983.941 1843541.2233,1161983.38 1843559.36,1161980.14 1843669.01,1161972.28 1843941,1161967.86 1844095.26,1161967.0954 1844118.8082,1161963.4023 1844232.5454,1161960.02 1844336.71,1161957.68 1844418.84,1161954.13 1844539.18,1161950.28 1844665.03,1161945.86 1844804.98,1161943.0513 1844896.35,1161939.8547 1845000,1161937.22 1845092.55,1161933.1224 1845226.2965,1161979.3215 1845230.7359,1161979.36 1845229.48,1162099.54 1845232.76,1162115.52 1845233.2,1162235.68 1845236.48,1162301.66 1845238.28,1162425.6 1845241.66,1162441.58 1845242.1201,1162565.5 1845245.5,1162631.48 1845247.32,1162755.38 1845250.72,1162771.36 1845251.14,1162895.24 1845254.5201,1162961.22 1845256.32,1163085.56 1845259.72,1163101.54 1845260.16,1163225.86 1845263.56,1163258.84 1845264.46,1163258.6249 1845271.7468,1163234.5022 1846088.7868,1163234.02 1846105.12,1163267.04 1846106.0401,1163391.22 1846109.46,1163390.48 1846134.44,1163389.74 1846159.44,1163389 1846184.42,1163387.2001 1846245.8,1163403.08 1846249.9999,1163496.94 1846271.72,1163526.5 1846277.7,1163542.7 1846280.82,1163559.32 1846284.68,1163590.04 1846291.8,1163592.0999 1846292.36,1163593.26 1846253.02,1163595.78 1846167.74,1163647.74 1846181.96,1163657.78 1846185.52,1163685.7799 1846195.46,1163698.52 1846199.98,1163710.22 1846205.14,1163734.2 1846215.72,1163747.8 1846221.72,1163757.88 1846227.08,1163780.62 1846239.22,1163795.3399 1846247.06,1163803.2801 1846252.08,1163825.24 1846265.96,1163840.88 1846275.8601,1163846.94 1846280.36,1163866.86 1846295.12,1163884.16 1846307.96,1163887.12 1846310.5,1163905.7 1846326.56,1163924.66 1846342.94,1163924.92 1846343.16,1163942.34 1846360.6201,1163959.98 1846378.3,1163962.98 1846381.3,1163976.62 1846397,1163993 1846415.84,1164037.3676 1846428.5616,1164139.3201 1846323.0901,1164158.0399 1846304.02,1164178.5299 1846283.5,1164244 1846217.92,1164278.82 1846181.44,1164320.3711 1846137.0909,1164354.41 1846100.76,1164372.27 1846083.12,1164493.28 1845958.44,1164515.94 1845933.96,1164519.47 1845928.8101,1164523.1 1845921.54,1164525.31 1845914.6699,1164526.1 1845907.22,1164526.53 1845901.5,1164524.83 1845890.77,1164523.12 1845886.14,1164518.49 1845876.38,1164514.11 1845868.58,1164507.29 1845859.56,1164490.1199 1845844.4,1164476.82 1845832.62,1164446.64 1845802.62,1164430.73 1845784.24,1164403.68 1845745.88,1164395.72 1845730.77,1164384.08 1845706.02,1164373.4 1845681.94,1164364.18 1845659.88,1164352.16 1845626.76,1164343.76 1845596.06,1164338.6001 1845569.48,1164334.23 1845530.73,1164333.32 1845511.28,1164333.28 1845494.88,1164334.48 1845452.88,1164336.56 1845436.96,1164336.8601 1845425.1699,1164335.3501 1845409.1399,1164333.84 1845402.18,1164330.82 1845393.1099,1164327.49 1845384.64,1164322.4201 1845376.51,1164315.14 1845364.86,1164305.69 1845354.66,1164276.4778 1845326.5478,1164334.16 1845244.21,1164384.18 1845172.69,1164428.18 1845109.97,1164460.34 1845064.01,1164475.8 1845041.91,1164496 1845013.65,1164504.9882 1845000,1164519.7978 1844977.5091,1164544.22 1844940.42,1164779.92 1844649.56,1164811.96 1844579.84,1164819.89 1844564.14,1164839.5362 1844526.503,1164910.681 1844428.9108,1164916.37 1844422.06,1164923.9 1844407.79,1164927.66 1844397.66,1164933.56 1844375.69,1164935.35 1844365.23,1164939.267 1844310.9456,1164939.6 1844306.33,1164941.04 1844262.65,1164942.18 1844231.4399,1164943.82 1844186.18,1164945.88 1844129.5201,1164951.38 1843989.92,1164951.83 1843968.0899,1164995.05 1843967.66,1165000 1843968.624,1165010.3 1843970.63,1165025.9 1843977.61,1165034.7 1843982.56,1165049.6 1843993.38,1165061.1 1844004.35,1165071.3 1844015.48,1165079.4999 1844026,1165087.34 1844037,1165095.95 1844048.98,1165100.28 1844054.32,1165106.56 1844061.4,1165117.02 1844070.38,1165129.01 1844078.57,1165138.02 1844083.52,1165153.24 1844089.6,1165166.02 1844093.61,1165181.81 1844095.62,1165193.84 1844094.61,1165205.6201 1844091.35,1165236.5418 1844057.6365,1165309.97 1844108.2,1165316.5401 1844112.38,1165339.36 1844130.95,1165382.43 1844164.63,1165383.7495 1844165.5507,1165445.04 1844208.32,1165505.4 1844242.74,1165542.7884 1844258.6126,1165613.66 1844288.7,1165643.3999 1844298.44,1165669.6401 1844306.18,1165702.73 1844314.47,1165734.02 1844320.94,1165780.9 1844327.99,1165813.8 1844331.18,1165841.15 1844333.84,1165859.0627 1844333.5264,1165876.56 1844333.22,1165893.24 1844327.86,1165937.43 1844321.32,1165948.87 1844317.51,1165963.48 1844315.6,1165971.74 1844316.24,1165985.72 1844322.6,1166007.67 1844334.58,1166017.4183 1844341.7355,1166022.57 1844348.04,1166030.83 1844361.4,1166042.9 1844395.75,1166047.57 1844413.8,1166060.29 1844456.69,1166067.4825 1844486.5996,1166097.9701 1844437.85))',0`
```

Comment: I can't double-check this, but they're state plane, probably Illinois East, in US survey feet, based on NAD83. Check the source, the info is likely there somewhere. The listed coords might be in y,x order.

Comment: Does that mean I can't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are combining features from different sources / spatial reference systems (SRS), then you need to reproject / align the layers to your target SRS (whether it is Lat/Long WGS84, Google Mercator, etc). MySQL Spatial and shp2MySQL cannot reproject spatial data (i.e., there is no [ST_Transform](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506210632/http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) function), so you need to either reproject your shapefile before loading, or directly load them using a loader program that is able to transform on-the-fly, like [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) (using the `-t_srs` option) or Safe FME.